# java.net.URL.getFile() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

So I need to pass a key (`.p12`) file `SERVICE_ACCT_KEYFILE` which is stored directly under the `res` folder in my Android project. I am setting the `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File()` as this:

```
private static GoogleCredential authorize() throws Exception {
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(
                        PredictionSample.class.getResource("/" + SERVICE_ACCT_KEYFILE).getFile()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION,
                        StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY))
                .build();
    }
```

This example works perfectly in Java and yet when I am trying to implement it in Android and I have the following error:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.net.URL.getFile()' on a null object reference`

Even doing this it fails:

```
String keyPath = "android.resource://" + MainActivity.PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.raw.pretense307cf970d6b1;

        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(
                        PredictionSample.class.getResource(keyPath).getFile()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(PredictionScopes.PREDICTION,
                        StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY))
                .build();
    }
```

How do I resolve the same?

Thanks.

Comment: android resources and java resources are not the same thing. see the doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: @njzk2 I realize that and I tried to translate. But no success. Any ideas?

Comment: you can't access the raw resources as `File`. But the doc I linked tells you how you can access to the content of the file.

Comment: @njzk2 Even if I access the content, how to I pass it to my specific function? Any sample code would be of great help!

Comment: you'll need to load the key using `SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a resource in an Android application, it should be located either in `src/main/res/raw` or `src/main/assets` directory. Android doesn't load resources via classloader.

If the `p12` file, say, `keyfile.p12` is in `src/main/res/raw` directory, it can be accessed this way:

```java
InputStream rawIs = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keyfile);
```

If `keyfile.p12` is in `src/main/assets` directory:

```java
InputStream assetIs = getAssets().open("keyfile.p12");
```

Then you'll need to save the `InputStream` into a `File`. You can create a file inside your app internal storage with `new File(getFilesDir(), "keyfile.p12")` or any method available in `Context` class that returns a directory for file storage instead of `getFilesDir()`. I leave the file copying code as an exercise :)

All of `getResources()`, `getAssets()` and `getFilesDir()` are instance methods of `Context` class.

Some reference, and explanation of the difference between raw and assets: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html