# Include arbitrary files in AAR file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Is there a way to include a directory containing arbitrary files inside an AAR? I'm using Android Studio + gradle.

These are not source code files or anything, but binary files.

Comment: you can add these files into the `assets` directory. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756426/2657100

Comment: Is there a way to do any "arbitrary" directory? Or is assets just the way to go with any random file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can create an entire directory hierarchy in the `assets` directory. Here's an example:

```
src
    main
        assets
            foo
                bar.txt (file)
                foo2
                    baz.bin (file)
```

Your assets will be packed into the AAR automatically.

With a context, you can access these files in the application that links to your AAR like this:

```java
InputStream barIs = getAssets().open("foo/bar.txt");
InputStream bazIs = getAssets().open("foo/foo2/baz.bin");
```